# Make Custom Cell swipeable (Without UITableViewController)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

So I have a UIViewController with a table view inside of it, which is the main reason why most of the questions like this don't apply to this. I want to make my cells swipeable and then make it possible to delete them etc.

How would I go about this?

What I've tried so far is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
self.tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
```

}

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

But they are not swipeable with this, and there is nothing happening. Neither is there a Edit button.

Comment: Are you extend your viewController from `UITableViewDataSource` protocol?

Comment: @pacification I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but I am not extending. I'm using another Framework to populate the cells, which is the datasource.

Comment: I was looking into this for the longest time and ended up just using a library on github because the frameworks from Apple aren't extensive enough for custom swipe animations.

Comment: @ggworean Could you recommend the framework you used?

Comment: MGSwipeTableCell. They've got nice animations and options for customization.

Comment: @ggworean I just discovered exactly that one 20 minutes ago, thanks a lot, it looks awesome.